# É possível ter uma constante populada através de um Spring @Service?

Tags: web-service, spring, soap, java-ee-7

Temos um web service que um de seus parâmetros é chamado de origem e esta origem sempre é validada contra um código no banco de dados.

Para cada um dos nossos serviços, eu tenho que validar este código. Este código não muda, então eu quero mantê-lo em uma constante, mas ainda tenho que validá-lo para evitar que os clientes enviem um código errado.

Basicamente, o que eu quero é o seguinte:

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private LogBS logBS;

    // Eu sei que a palavra reservada "this" não pode ser utilizada em contexto estático.
    public static final Long CODIGO_LOG_WEB_SERVICE = this.logBS.recuperarCodigoLogWebService("webServiceName");

    public void validarCodigoOrigem(final Long origem) {
        if (!origem.equals(CODIGO_LOG_WEB_SERVICE)) {
            throw new ServiceException("Código de web service errado!");
        }
    }
}
```

Eu sei que algo semelhante pode ser feito com o Spring cache, mas é possível fazê-lo com uma constante?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz a mesma [pergunta no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45830072/1630619) e obtive a seguinte [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45831821/1630619) traduzida e melhorada abaixo:

Prefiro a seguinte maneira:

```
@Service
public class CodeValidatorServiceImpl implements CodeValidatorService {

    private final LogBS logBS;
    private final Long CODE;

    @Autowired
    public CodeValidatorServiceImpl(final LogBS logBS){
        this.logBS = logBS;
        CODE = this.logBS.retrieveLogWebServiceCode("webServiceName");
        if (CODE == null){
            throw new ServiceException("Code cannot be read from DB!");
        }
    }

    public void validateOriginCode(final Long origin) {
        if (!origin.equals(CODE)) {
            throw new ServiceException("Wrong origin code!");
       }
   }
}
```

Uma revisão de código: prefiro injetar dependências no construtor ao invés de usar `@Autowired` no campo diretamente, pois isto torna o `@Service` testável. Você também pode tentar ler o código no método anotado com `@PostConstruct`, mas acho que é melhor fazê-lo no construtor para que você sempre tenha o `@Service` em um estado pronto para uso.

Para usá-lo no resto de seus `@Service`s, injete a instância `CodeValidatorService` neles:

```
@Service
public class OtherService {

    private CodeValidatorService codeValidatorService;

    @Autowired
    public OtherService(CodeValidatorService codeValidatorService){
        this.codeValidatorService = codeValidatorService;
    }

    public void performAction(final Long origin) {
        codeValidatorService.validateOriginCode(origin);
        //do the rest of your logic here
   }
}
```

**Referências oficiais Spring (em inglês):**

- [Spring Beans and dependency injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html)
- [Setter injection versus constructor injection](https://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/)